# Android: Ongoing Notification disappears when pressing on a custom button within remoteView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Trying to figure out why my onGoing notification disappears when the user presses on the pause button.  I am trying to implement a media player controls scheme similar to that of the Spotify ongoing notification. I am modifying Androids Sample project "RandomMusicPlayer". I have tried setting setAutoCancel to false.

Related code listed below:

```
/** Updates the notification. */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void updateNotification(String text, String artist, boolean showticker) {
    Notification notification = buildNotification(text, artist, showticker);
    if(notification!=null){
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}

/**
 * Configures service as a foreground service. A foreground service is a service that's doing
 * something the user is actively aware of (such as playing music), and must appear to the
 * user as a notification. That's why we create the notification here.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setUpAsForeground(String text, String artist, boolean showticker) {
    Notification notification = buildNotification(text, artist, showticker);
    if(notification != null){
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when we want to build our notification
 */
private Notification buildNotification(String title, String artist, boolean showticker){
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class).setAction(ACTION_OPEN_STREAM_FRAG),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent pendingStopIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 118, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_STOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    PendingIntent pendingPauseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 119, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PAUSE), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 120, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    RemoteViews mNotificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.player_notification_view);

    Notification mNotification = null;

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    mNotificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageNotification, R.drawable.ic_launcher );
    mNotificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.titleNotification, title);
    mNotificationView.setTextColor(R.id.titleNotification, Color.WHITE);
    mNotificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.textNotification, artist);


    if(mState == State.Playing){
        mNotificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.control_one_button_notification, R.drawable.ic_action_playback_pause);
        mNotificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.control_two_button_notification, R.drawable.ic_action_playback_stop);
        mNotificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.control_one_button_notification, pendingPauseIntent);
        mNotificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.control_two_button_notification, pendingStopIntent);
    }else if(mState == State.Paused){
        mNotificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.control_one_button_notification, R.drawable.ic_action_playback_play);
        mNotificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.control_two_button_notification, R.drawable.ic_action_playback_stop);
        mNotificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.control_one_button_notification, pendingPlayIntent);
        mNotificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.control_two_button_notification, pendingStopIntent);
    }

    builder.setContentIntent(pi).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    if(showticker){
        builder.setTicker(title);
    }else{
        builder.setTicker(null);
    }
    builder.setAutoCancel(false).setContent(mNotificationView).setOngoing(true);
    mNotification = builder.build();

    return mNotification;
}
```

Comment: gives me a suggestion. I build a notification big view using RemoteView to control play/pause like this link (stackoverflow.com/questions/14508369/…) All are right but when i click device back button and out from the application click event(Play/Pause/Forward/Close) button doesn't work.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you do but you should implement this in a `Service`, and there you should use:

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

I have made an app that does just this, please have a look at how I solved it here: https://github.com/slidese/SGU

Specifically, look at this class: https://github.com/slidese/SGU/blob/master/src/se/slide/sgu/AudioPlayer.java

Comment: Im still getting the same issue when trying it the way you had implemented it...I must be doing something wrong somewhere else. I have a feeling its something with the way I call the pending Intents.  The track IS pausing but the notification will disappear. Ive updated my post to show latest code.

Comment: What are you doing when you're pausing? How are you updating the notification.

Comment: Wow that was it...didn't realize I was stopping the foreground service when I paused.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a code in your function of pendingIntent

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(01);
//"01" is the id of your notification
```

or refer to link 
[How to stop a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208098/programatically-ending-an-ongoing-notification-android)